# Disable client validation while clicking certain buttons in a form in mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, client-side-validation

i am having an mvc 2 application in which i have a form that contains two buttons

```
 <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<%using(Html.BeginForm()){ %>
            <%= Html.LabelFor(m=> m.FormName) %>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.FormName) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FormName) %>
   <input type="submit" name="BtnSegment" value="Add" class="button_99" title="Add" />
    <input type="submit" name="BtnSave" value="Save" class="button_99"  title="Save" />
<%} %>
```

Now my requirement is to disable validation when the user clicks `Add` button.
But validate when the user clicks `Save` Button.
thanks,
suraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MSAjax for client side validation you could do this:

```
<input type="submit" name="BtnSegment" disableValidation="true" value="Add" class="button_99" title="Add" />
```

Notice the `disableValidation` attribute on the button. Obviously that's invalid HTML Transitional and you could cheat by appending this attribute using javascript:

```
document.getElementById('idOfYourButton').disableValidation = true;
```

Still stinky but at least the validator will be happy.

Personally I consider MSAjax library a crap. With the [jquery.validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) (which by the way is the default client side validation mechanism in ASP.NET MVC 3) you simlpy apply the `cancel` class to the button:

```
<input type="submit" name="BtnSegment" value="Add" class="button_99 cancel" title="Add" />
```